# how to Start At X position on a live feed on youtube

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, android-youtube-api

So, I'm trying to show a live stream on Youtube inside my android app, I've been able to go until this point, either trough a WebView or Android Youtube API. 
My problem is, that I need the video to start the stream not live, but 30 seconds previous to current opening point and play it, even if you set the "t=" you will get back to the live moment, and the entered time will be dismissed, so my question is, is there a solution for this?? thanks!!!

Comment: did you try to use the seekTo() in javaScript, also there is a similar method in for Android Java API

Comment: yes, they both fail, as the Live button doesn't seem to turn off so it goes to current position. You can see the same behavior if you add a 't=' attribute to a stream pointing to any position it will go always to Live.

Comment: I have not tried them, but based on the Android api docs, it says that this method can take you forward or backwards relative milliseconds, seekRelativeMillis(int milliSeconds), Seeks forward or backwards by the specified number of seconds.